# For which values of $p$ the series $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\ln^p{n}}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

I'm trying to find all values of $p$ for which the following series converges:

$$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\ln^p{n}}$$

So my first approach was to use the integral test because $\frac{1}{\ln^p{n}}$ is monotone decreasing, continuous and non-negative, but I don't know how to calculate such an integral...

In my second approach I found that in the interval $[0, 1]$, we have $\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{\ln^p n}$ and I know that $\frac{1}{n}$ diverges and also non-negative so for $p \in [0, 1]$ the series diverges.

But that's not enough... How should I solve this?

Comment: Hint: comparison with $1/n$ works for $p>1$ as well.

Comment: @Wojowu can you please show how to calculate that? I basically need to solve the inequality $n \geq \frac{1}{\ln^p n}$

Comment: Hint to calm you down: it does not converge for $p \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2):

In many cases series involving logarithms can be easily handled using [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), which states that if $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing, then 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k
$$
converges if and only if
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^k a_{2^k}
$$
converges. With this you will easily find out for which $p$ your series converges.